# drawing will not shown on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, drawing

i want draw a circle on my webpage so i have downloaded two different javascript for drawing a circle.one of js file is downloaded from http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/ 
then i have use its function to draw circle but circle is not shown on html page i have try
both internet explorer and mozilla firefox but niether it give error nor it will draw circle
so what are reson behind this. same problrm arise when using both js file.

thanks in advance

```
<HEAD>
 <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="wz_jsgraphics/wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myDrawFunction()
 {


      jg2.setColor("#0000ff"); // blue
      jg2.drawEllipse(10, 50, 230, 100);
      jg2.drawRect(400, 10, 100, 50);
      jg2.paint();
       alert("hi");
}
var jg2 = new jsGraphics(document.getElementById("canvas"));
</script>

<BODY >
<div id="canvas" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:600px;height:300px;"></div> 
<input type="submit" onclick="myDrawFunction()" value="Click"> 
<p> hi this is paragraph</p>
</div>
</BODY>
```

Comment: some sample code would be of great help here...

Comment: using a submit button for calling javascript is not the best idea...

Comment: your second </div> is wrong too - just remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using document.getElementById before the page did load!

```
var jg2 = new jsGraphics(document.getElementById("canvas"));
```

Is called in your head as soon as it is parsed.

Change it to:

```
var jg2 = null;
function myDrawFunction()
 {
    if(jg2 == null)
       jg2 = new jsGraphics(document.getElementById("canvas"));
    jg2.setColor("#0000ff"); // blue
    jg2.drawEllipse(10, 50, 230, 100);
    jg2.drawRect(400, 10, 100, 50);
    jg2.paint();
    alert("hi");
}
```